# How to properly get LinkedIn company updates using the API?

Tags: api, linkedin-api, updates

I cant seem to get a proper return of company updates (shares) via the LinkedIn API: https://developer.linkedin.com/reading-company-shares

When I make a request for company updates with event type "new-hire" of lets say The Coca Cola company my endpoint is:

api.linkedin.com/v1/companies/1694/updates?event-type=new-hire

This gives me a result of 0

```
[@attributes] => Array
(
    [total] => 0
)
```

However when making a request for company updates with event type "status update" my endpoint is:

api.linkedin.com/v1/companies/1694/updates?event-type=status-update

This gives no result but a status 500 API sever error.

```
[status] => 500
[timestamp] => 1390384395039
[request-id] => 2O14IFML4X
[error-code] => 0
[message] => Internal API server error
```

Am I doing something wrong? Is my API endpoint not correct? Or is this a LinkedIn API bug. I've found posts of other developers having similar problems.

Comment: You need to be a administrator within the company. There is also a test company set up by LinkedIn with reduced limits which you can use. `https://www.linkedin.com/company/devtestco` companyid `2414183`

Answer (score 1):

You need to use oauth2_access_token to get data like this https://api.linkedin.com/v1/companies/id/updates?oauth2_access_token=access_token&format=json&event-type=job-posting&count=250

Comment: how to get access_token ??